# Определить количество элементов массива, которые меньше среднего арифметического значения всех элементов своей строки

Tags: c++, массивы, динамические-массивы

Дан вещественный массив А[N][М].

1. Выводит неверное число элементов.
2. Не смог написать это число для каждой строки массива.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime>
using namespace std;
 
int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "");
    srand(unsigned(time(NULL)));
    int N, M, j, i;
    cout << "Введите размер матрицы: ";
    cin >> N >> M; // N - строка M - столб
    int** A = new int* [N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        A[i] = new int[M];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
        {
              cin >> A[i][j];
        }
    }
        
    cout << " " << endl;

 cout << "Ваша матрица:" << endl << endl;

    cout << " " << endl;

 for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
 {
     for(int j = 0; j < M; j++)
         cout << A[i][j] << " ";
     cout << endl;
 }
 int *sum = new int[M];
 int hel = 0;

 for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
 {
     sum[i] = 0;
     for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
     {
         sum[i] = sum[i] + A[i][j];
        

     }
     sum[i] = sum[i] / N;
     for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
     {
         if (sum[j] < sum[i])
         {
             hel++;
         }

     }
 }

 cout << "Количество элементов массива меньше ср. арифметического: " << hel << endl;

 cout << endl;
 for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
 {
     delete[] A[i];
 }
        delete [] A;

        system("pause > void");
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы искал это число так:

```
int *sum = new int[N];
for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
{
    sum[i] = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < M; ++j) sum[i] += A[i][j]; // сумма
    int less = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < M; ++j)
        if (A[i][j] * M < sum[i]) ++less;         // количество чисел, меньше среднего
    sum[i] = less;
}
```

Вот тут - https://ideone.com/BXQ3N1 - полный новый код, с выводом сразу при выводе матрицы (я только, чтоб не возиться, заполнял ее случайными числами).

Answer (score 0):

Исправьте,

```
sum[i] = sum[i] / N;
 for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
 {
     if (А[i][j] < sum[i])
     {
         hel++;
     }

 }
```

Вы сравнивание средние, а по заданию вы должны были сравнить элементы строки

Comment: Изменил, но программа все равно не выдает нужные данные, помогите исправить

Answer (score 0):

Не нужно путать строки и столбцы. И sum ни к чему делать массивом, если оно больше не понадобится

```
 int sum;
 int hel = 0;

 for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
 {
     sum = 0;
     for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
         sum += A[i][j];
     for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
         if (A[i][j] * M < sum)
             hel++;
 }
```